# Could someone describe different methods for turning another character into magical armor?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am interested in transforming a defeated boss into a series armor based objects that grants the racial traits of the transformed for other individuals in game, could someone describe any spells or classes, or curses that a player character could use to accomplish this? I am interested in it working similar to the Fusion Spell for Psions, and would like to avoid wise spell if possible. I do not have access to every book available and wanted to gather some of ideas. Weird Idea but I wanna see if it could be done.

Comment: ok just to be sure I understand you. You want to turn a creature into a suit of armor, that bestows the racial traits of the transformed creature unto it's wearer?

Comment: You appear to have accidentally created a second account and posted a duplicate question. You should consult the instructions for [how to merge accounts](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), and once you have control over the original account's questions again, you should edit your original question (which is on hold at the moment) until it is clarified enough for the community to be able to answer it. (What need clarifying in particular has been posted as comments on the original question.) Thanks!